# Using Scala macros, can i make implementer of method call super?

Tags: scala, inheritance, scala-macros

Can Scala macros be used to make implementers of a method in a trait invoke the super method. For instance like this:

```
trait Super {
  //some macro magic here: list = super.list ++ child.list
  def list: List[String] = List("ein", "zwei", "DIE")
}

class Sub extends Super {
  override def list: List[String] = List("4", "5")
}

object Testy extends App {
  println(new Sub().list) //List(ein, zwei, DIE, 4, 5)
}
```

---

Update:
See comment from @Sergey below - this is not really doable with macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need macros in this particular case. In order to enforce some data from a superclass' method to be added to all results of implementing methods in any subclass, the preferred approach would be to use a template method. Make a `final def` performing the addition of the fixed part and an abstract `def` declaring the variable part, like so:

```
trait Super {
  protected def additionalList: List[String]
  final def list: List[String] = List("ein", "zwei", "DIE") ++ additionalList
}

class Sub extends Super {
  protected val additionalList = List("4", "5")
}

object Testy extends App {
  println(new Sub().list) // List(ein, zwei, DIE, 4, 5)
}
```

Update: If, however, you need exactly the behavior as specified in the original question, then you're out of luck, I fear: a macro can only affect what it immediately wraps, e.g. a def macro can only transform what is passed into the method, and an annotation macro can only transform its immediate annottee, be it a class, a field, a method, etc. There's no way for a macro to enforce rules on code which doesn't even know about the macro. So basically you have two options: either make your users call `super` manually, or write an annotation macro and have your users annotate their subclasses with it. Both of these options are easy to omit, unfortunately.

Comment: Creative approach, but Sub needs to be able implement the list function for my use case as this is what the programmers that implement Super will expect to work.

Comment: Then you're out of luck on this case, I fear: a macro can only affect what it immediately wraps, e.g. a def macro can only transform what is passed into the method, and an annotation macro can only transform the literal it annotates, be it class, field, whatever; there's no way for a macro to enforce rules on code which doesn't even know about the macro.

So basically you have two options: either make your users call `super` manually, or write an annotation macro and have your users annotate their subclasses with it. Both of them are easy to omit, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This comment sounds like the answer to the question. If you post as answer I'll accept. I ended up writing in the doc that clients need to call super and prepend results to their own implementation.

Comment: Nevermind re-answering, I'll just accept your answer.